# Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... error

Tags: python, numpy

I have created a python app in my namecheap cpanel. I uploaded by server files in that and also UI files in public_html. However, I was getting Internal Server Error 500. Then I contacted their customer service. They told me install joblib through terminal. I installed it. Then they said in my root folder a file named "stderr.log" it said numpy is missing. So I tried to install numpy. But it shows the following error. Even customer service person failed to provide a solution. When I try **pip install numpy**, it shows the following large error. Please help.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
  Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [61 lines of output]
      Running from numpy source directory.
      setup.py:67: DeprecationWarning:

        `numpy.distutils` is deprecated since NumPy 1.23.0, as a result
        of the deprecation of `distutils` itself. It will be removed for
        Python >= 3.12. For older Python versions it will remain present.
        It is recommended to use `setuptools < 60.0` for those Python versions.
        For more details, see:
          https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/distutils_status_migration.html


        import numpy.distutils.command.sdist
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/alt/python39/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
          return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
        File "/opt/alt/python39/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
          exec(code, run_globals)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r6jq5if_/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/cython.py", line 16, in <module>
          from Cython.Compiler.Main import main
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r6jq5if_/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 28, in <module>
          from .Scanning import PyrexScanner, FileSourceDescriptor
      ImportError: /tmp/pip-build-env-r6jq5if_/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Scanning.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted
      Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random/_pcg64.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-q0hfnoqk/numpy_6a92dfb088184f0aaac1f9f1f3acc80e/tools/cythonize.py", line 205, in <module>
          main()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-q0hfnoqk/numpy_6a92dfb088184f0aaac1f9f1f3acc80e/tools/cythonize.py", line 201, in main
          find_process_files(root_dir)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-q0hfnoqk/numpy_6a92dfb088184f0aaac1f9f1f3acc80e/tools/cythonize.py", line 192, in find_process_files
          process(root_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-q0hfnoqk/numpy_6a92dfb088184f0aaac1f9f1f3acc80e/tools/cythonize.py", line 158, in process
          processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-q0hfnoqk/numpy_6a92dfb088184f0aaac1f9f1f3acc80e/tools/cythonize.py", line 47, in process_pyx
          subprocess.check_call(
        File "/opt/alt/python39/lib64/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/nahiuzfc/virtualenv/classify_image/3.9/bin/python3.9_bin', '-m', 'cython', '-3', '--fast-fail', '-o', '_pcg64.c', '_pcg64.pyx']' returned non-zeroexit status 1.
      Cythonizing sources
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/nahiuzfc/virtualenv/classify_image/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/nahiuzfc/virtualenv/classify_image/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/nahiuzfc/virtualenv/classify_image/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r6jq5if_/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 230, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r6jq5if_/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 215, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r6jq5if_/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r6jq5if_/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 479, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "setup.py", line 458, in setup_package
          generate_cython()
        File "setup.py", line 261, in generate_cython
          raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed!")
      RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```